# Passing a color variable between private voids

Tags: c#

Color c = Colors.Red;

How can I pass the color variable above from one private void to another?
Thanks in advance
Stephanie

```
private void btnRedClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Color c = Colors.Red;
}

private void inkCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (inkCanvas.EditingMode == InkCanvasEditingMode.None)
    {
        if(dtm == DrawingToolMode.ellipse)
        {
            Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();
            //Color c = Colors.Red;
            System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush scb =
            new SolidColorBrush(c);
            myEllipse.Stroke = (scb);
            myEllipse.Fill = (scb);
            Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(this.inkCanvas);
            InkCanvas.SetTop(myEllipse, p.Y);
            InkCanvas.SetLeft(myEllipse, p.X);
            myEllipse.Height = 20;
            myEllipse.Width = 20;
            inkCanvas.Children.Add(myEllipse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: create a class member variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in a private field:

```
private Color _color;

private void btnRedClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _color = Colors.Red;

}

private void inkCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Color myLocalColor = _color;
}
```

I suggest you read up on programming 101 though. This is a very elementary question.

Comment: It is not. We posted at the same time. Concurrency issue ;)

Answer (score 5):

Declare your Color like this:

```
private Color c = Color.Blue; // Set default color

private void btnRedClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       c = Color.Red;
    }

    private void inkCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (inkCanvas.EditingMode == InkCanvasEditingMode.None)
        {
            if(dtm == DrawingToolMode.ellipse)
            {
                Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();
                System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush scb =
                new SolidColorBrush(c);
                myEllipse.Stroke = (scb);
                myEllipse.Fill = (scb);
                Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(this.inkCanvas);
                InkCanvas.SetTop(myEllipse, p.Y);
                InkCanvas.SetLeft(myEllipse, p.X);
                myEllipse.Height = 20;
                myEllipse.Width = 20;
                inkCanvas.Children.Add(myEllipse);
            }
        }

    }
```